# Knative Eventing KafkaSource issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, knative

I’ve got an issue with Knative Eventing and I would like to have your help as I am fresh about it. 
I am using Knative v0.10.0, minikube v1.5.2, Docker v19.03.1 and Kafka 2.3.1 (used as the source of events). I developed a kafka producer and a kafka consumer using Kafka Java client APIs and Spring Boot. They work in pipeline so I have a CronJobSource that wakes up my producer each X minutes, the producer sends some events to a Kafka Topic, then I configured a KafkaSource that listen to that topic and should wakes up the consumer. Actually, the KafkaSource does nothing even if everything seems to be configured well, I tried to log KafkaSource, but it has no errors or succeed logs. Both producer and consumer can work well if I wake up them manually without passing through KafkaSource.

This is my KafkaSource yaml file configuration:

```
apiVersion: sources.eventing.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaSource
metadata:
  name: ods-datamartextractor-kafka-source
spec:
  consumerGroup: ods-dataconverter-consumer-group-id
  bootstrapServers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092
  topics: datamartextractor-topic
  sink:
    ref:
        apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
        kind: Service
        name: ods-dataconverter-service
```

This is my kafka producer code:

```
@Service
public class ODSDataMartExtractor {

public void sendEvent(DataMart dataMart) {
        String event = dataMart.toString();
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> " + event));
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("datamartextractor-topic", event);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                System.out.println("Sent message=[" + event + "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to send message=[" + event + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

kafka producer config:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

kafka consumer code:

```
@Service
public class ODSDataConverter {

@KafkaListener(topics = "datamartextractor-topic", groupId = "ods-dataconverter-consumer-group-id")
    public void consumeEvent(String event) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> " + event));
    }
}
```

kafka consumer config:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "ods-dataconverter-consumer-group-id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe show your Kafka code?

Comment: Question edited with kafka code

Comment: Thanks. How do you know `future.addCallback` is actually being completed? Based on what you've said, the thread is ending without the producer acknowledging a write... And Kafka Producers do not immediately send events, they get batched into larger messages, so maybe try sending more data

Comment: Even sending more data the problem persist

Comment: Are you able to see the callback events in the logs?

Comment: Yes, the callback events are ok, the producer is able to write on the topic, but now the Kafka Source log report the following error: {"level":"error","ts":"2020-01-22T17:11:28.348Z","caller":"adapter/adapter.go:178","msg":"An error has occurred while consuming messages occurred: {error 25 0  context canceled}","stacktrace":"knative.dev/eventing-contrib/kafka/source/pkg/adapter.(*Adapter).Start.func3\n\t/home/prow/go/src/knative.dev/eventing-contrib/kafka/source/pkg/adapter/adapter.go:178"}

Comment: And what code is at `knative.dev/eventing-contrib/kafka/source/pkg/adapter/adapter.go:178`?